# Spring security remember me

Tags: spring, spring-security, remember-me

As per [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me) link, I'm trying to implement the Persistent Token Approach for the "remember me" functionality. The tokens are stored in my database (postgres). I have the datasource set up properly, however, when I try doing:

```
<remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />
```

My database does not get populated with the token data automatically. Otherwise, the "remember me" functionality works well (only the database doesn't get populated automatically). Any ideas why?

Table ddl:

```
create table users(
    uid serial primary key,
    username varchar(255) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    firstname varchar(255) not null,
    lastname varchar(255) not null,
    enabled boolean not null,
    constraint cs_username_unq unique(username),
    constraint cs_uid_username_unq unique(uid, username)
);

create table authorities (
    username varchar(255) not null,
    authority varchar(255) not null,
    constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username)
);

create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);

create table persistent_logins (
    username varchar(255) not null,
    series varchar(255) primary key,
    token varchar(255) not null,
    last_used timestamp not null
);
```

Comment: Did you created the table in your database? can you post the DDL?

Comment: yes, i did. updated my ans.

Comment: the only thing I note is that you are using varchar(255) instead of varchar(64), does varchar in postgre pads strings?

Comment: Any exceptions? What do you see when you enable debug logging for Spring Security?

Comment: Could you please post your (security) configuration.xml.